# JQuery .html() strips tr/td tags?

Tags: jquery, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/WXG7V/

As you can see below, I have a simple div containing a row I would like to append to the end of my table.  If I alert the contents of the div back to the screen using ".html()", jQuery strips out all of the td/tr tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Strips Table Tags</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

            alert($("#newRow").html());
            $(".tasks > tbody:last").append($("#newRow").html());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tasks" style="margin-left: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Feeder ID</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th># Reels</th>
                <th>Reel Length</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Colour</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<div id="newRow" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="feeder_id" id="feeder_id" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="from" id="from" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="to" id="to" /></td>
        <td><select name="number" id="number">
            <option value=1>1</option>
            <option value=2>2</option>
            <option value=3>3</option>
            <option value=4>4</option>
            <option value=6>6</option>
            <option value=8>8</option>
            <option value=9>9</option>
            <option value=12>12</option>
            <option value=14>14</option>
            <option value=16>16</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="length" id="length" /></td>
        <td><select name="type" id="type"><option value="CU">Copper</option><option value="AL">Aluminum</option></select></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="colour" id="black" value="black" />Black
        <input type="radio" name="colour" id="red" value="red" />Red
        <input type="radio" name="colour" id="blue" value="blue" />Blue
        <input type="radio" name="colour" id="white" value="white" />White
        <input type="radio" name="colour" id="green" value="green" />Green
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<tr>`, `<td>` are only valid elements inside `<table>`. Use `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` in conjunction with `<div>` to replace the `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Example:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
        Foo
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table{
     display: table;
}
.row {
     display: table-row;
}
.cell {
     display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I wrapped the hidden `<tr>` in a `<table>` tag and changed my append html to `$("#newRow table tbody").html()` instead... that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: What is the good solution? I don't get why this answer is right I want to use the td and tr elements and not some divs to clone their behavior.

Comment: @sirwilliam The problem was that the OP put `<tr>` and `<td>` inside a non-table tag. The tags were dropped by the browser, not by jQuery. Instead of changing the tags, the OP can also replace `<div id="newRow" ...>...</div>` with `<table id="newRow" ...>...</div>`. Then, in order to use the template, call `.append($('#newRow tr').clone())` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwmc3/)).

Comment: @RobW So I have to send an table like `<table><tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr></table>` and then use .html to grab the td's.

Comment: Ok got it working, maybe you can update your answer for future askers. I now send a complete table and then I get just the td's I need with `var html = $('tr', this).html();` this is the element returned by my ajax call I loop through with `$(data).filter(function(){ //load all pieces of html });`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for templating, I would recommend checking out [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Then you could simply wrap your existing html in a tag `<script id="newRow" type="text/x-handlebars-template">` and keep the rest of your markup in the same format you started with.